# How do I open minecraft.jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\versions\1.7.4, %appdata%.minecraft\versions and %appdata%.minecraft     Everytime I try opening the Java(.jar)file, it does nothing, can someone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Staring the game, or something else?

Comment: I want to change the Splashes

Comment: "How to open a JAR file" is not specific to games in any way and is therefore off-topic on Arqade.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about how to mod Minecraft, which is off topic on Arqade.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to games in any way and is therefore off-topic on Arqade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download WinRar or 7zip, you need a program like these to open Minecraft.jar
[Winrar Download](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm)
when downloaded the program right click Minecraft.jar, select open with, select winrar, and there you go.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see what you are trying to achieve by opening the jar file.

Keep in mind that the new launcher will overwrite any edits made to the default versions; nor are the splashes stored in the version jar anymore.

You're likely looking to create a [Resource Pack](http://minecraftwiki.net/Resource_pack), which you can edit the Splashes, and other things.