# How to open Minecraft_Server.jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I downloaded `minecraft_server1.8.8.jar` I couldn't open it by double clicking on it, nothing would happen.

I tried opening the `eula.txt` file and changed `eula=false` to `eula=true` so I'm still confused as to why it doesn't work.

What do I need to do to open the `minecraft_server.jar` file?

Comment: You can't open/run jar files like that (unless its part of your path variable). To open it, you need a program like 7zip or winrar. You can looked at the pacakged contents (although they are just compiled code so its all nonsense).  To actually use it, there is a special command, @Aequitas has that in his answer. In general, to run jar files though you can simply go to your cmd and type cd locationOfFile, then java -jar filename.jar

Comment: "How to open a jar file" is not specific to Minecraft in any way, making this question off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not specific to gaming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open minecraft.jar?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146268/how-do-i-open-minecraft-jar)

Answer (score 4):

`jar` files need to be open with Java;

---

**Windows**

Go to the folder that the `.jar` file is located. Then push <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> type in *cmd* and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open cmd.exe with the location set to the correct spot, otherwise you could change directory with the `cd (directory)` command.

Now just type in `java -jar minecraft_server1.8.8.jar` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the file.

---

**Linux**

Open the Terminal: Applcations > Accessories > Terminal. and then change directories to where the Minecraft server jar is located with the `cd` command. Then type in `java -jar minecraft_server.jar`

---

Additional arguments:

- You can add `no gui` to the end of the command to open the server without the GUI
- You can specify the initial and maximum memory allocation pool for the Java Virtual Machine by adding `-Xms500M` and `-Xmx1G` between `java` and `-jar`. You can change the size (the `500M` and `1G` parts) to whatever you like. The default value for `xmx` is 256MB, if you encounter a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` you may need to increase `xmx` when you start it with this command line.

Comment: @Minecraft sorry I had a typo, it should be an `_` not a `.` I've edited my answer

Comment: mine opens as a text file any help?
I tried everything

Comment: You know, "no gui" is not correct. `nogui` it has to be.